# How to implement auto archiving for log file using Log4Net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I want to configure log4net in such a manner that all the previous day logs should be archived automatically. Is there any possibility to auto archive previous logs in Log4Net. I want to do this using the configuration only without writing any code using any third party library like sharplibzip to create archive.

One more thing to add by archiving i mean compressing file in zip/rar format to save disk space.

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to archive files without writing code, sorry. However the code would not be very complicated.

You can create a custom appender inheriting from the `RollingFileAppender`, and override the `AdjustFileBeforeAppend` method in order to add behavior to the file rolling. Here is the existing method that rolls the file for the `RollingFileAppender` that you can override to add archiving.

Use the `File` property to find the file name process it

```
// log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
protected virtual void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
{
    var fileToZip = File; // save the current file
    if (this.m_rollDate)
    {
        DateTime now = this.m_dateTime.Now;
        if (now >= this.m_nextCheck)
        {
            this.m_now = now;
            this.m_nextCheck = this.NextCheckDate(this.m_now, this.m_rollPoint);
            this.RollOverTime(true);
            // zip the file if roll occurs here
        }
    }
    if (this.m_rollSize)
    {
        if (this.File != null && ((CountingQuietTextWriter)base.QuietWriter).Count >= this.m_maxFileSize)
        {
            this.RollOverSize();
            // zip the file if roll occurs here
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could find an existing appender that does what you want, but I don't know of any.

---

I'm taking the liberty of lifting @stuartd's comment into the answer since what he proposes is quite elegant. You can simply override the `AdjustFileBeforeAppend` in this way:

```
protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend() {
    var previousFile = File;
    base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();
    if (File != previousFile) { // zip the file }
}
```

It is quite a neat way of doing it, but you may want to be able to differentiate between both kind of rolls (ie date and size). For example only zipping on date roll in order to keep the files for a date range together.

Comment: To avoid having to replace the code in the existing method which isn't the best idea in the long run, it could be done like this:

protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
        {
            var previousFile = File;
            base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();
            if (File != previousFile)
            {
               // zip the file
            }
        }

Comment: That's a very good idea! I think that it doesn't hurt to differentiate between size rolling and date rolling, since you may want to zip files for the same day together. Too bad we cannot award rep on comments

Comment: log4net is inspired by log4j. The successor to log4j is called logback, and has zipping built into the configuration, so it has exactly what you (and I)  want.  Now we just need some inspired team to write logback.NET !

Comment: I don't understand, who cares to call this logic? and who cares to do it only for old files?

Comment: I tried use this logic but got compilation errors:        'myProject.BL.MyCustomAppender' does not contain a definition for 'm_rollSize' and no extension method 'm_rollSize' accepting a first argument of type ' myProject.BL.MyCustomAppender ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). THERE WAS NOT ANY OPTION FOR USING TO ADD.

Comment: Why should that work? ActivateOptions is the only place where the File property is changed. File is the name of the file it should currently log to, i.e. the newest file. This keeps being the same after rolling.

Actually trying this out also shows that File never changes after a roll

Comment: @poizan42 it might work depending on all the settings (I think you can change if rolling counts up or down and if you always want to write to the primary file or not).

Comment: I am trying it in .net core but it doesn't seem to work. Please check https://gist.github.com/KamranShahid/cbb2d04691b0862938b72d83100e9e93

Comment: @samy can i get your full implementation

Answer (score 3):

log4net does not contain any functionality for compressing log files. However compression is in the .Net framework (since 4.5) or you could use [the Windows Shell API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12064/Compress-Zip-files-with-Windows-Shell-API-and-C) to zip the files, so you would have code which periodically gets all the log files which aren't the current log file and zip them up:

```
-- assuming you don't have more that one appender
appender = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders()
                     .OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault();

if (appender == null) return; // no appenders found

var currentFile = appender.File;

-- dropping to pseudocode:
var files = Get_all_files_in_log_directory_which_match_log_file_pattern 
         but_aren't_the_current_file(current file);

if (ZipFiles(files...))
    (DeleteFiles(files); // presumably
```

Comment: Hi @stuartd. Can you please what wrong i  am doing in https://gist.github.com/KamranShahid/cbb2d04691b0862938b72d83100e9e93

Comment: @KamranShahid not really. If it isn't working, you might want to consider posting a question with full details as to what the problem is?

Comment: In my case log are rotating on filesize file is not archiving. iwant to delete old file after archiving

Comment: Maybe you should step through the code. As an aside I seem to remember it is not recommended to call the methods on `ILog` in a custom appender, as you could end out in a loop, and you should use [`LogLog`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Util_LogLog.htm) instead.

Comment: What i simply want is only currently used file will remain as text file while old file will be zip and removed. If there are multiple file in a day because of size then it should be added in the current day zip file as entries. ILog is working for day over rolling. but for the same day with multiple file above logic doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: No Problem @stuartd. You helped in lots of things. if not this time then it's not a big thing

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution using DotNetZip reduced.

```
public class CustomRollingFileAppender : RollingFileAppender
    {
        protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
        {
            var currentFile = File;

            FileInfo fa = new System.IO.FileInfo(currentFile);

            if (fa.Length >= 10000000)
            {
                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(File + ".zip"))
                {
                    string newFile =  DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + fa.Name;
                    zip.AddFile(File).FileName = newFile;
                    zip.Save(File + ".zip");
                }
            }

            base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Working solution, but in my opinion has a nightmarish performance overhead due to calling FileInfo for every single write.samys solution seems way more io-friendly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that the only way to realize this properly is to entirely copy the `RollingFileAppender` source code and create a subclass of `FileAppender` from it. In this code, you can then add the compressing part in `adjustFileBeforeAppend()`.

The suggestions by samy above do not work

1. Because the first code snippet uses private members (which you cannot access in a subclass)
2. Because the second code snippet assumes that the current log file name contains the date or so. But actually, the date pattern is only applied for all old files, not the current one. So you cannot determine if the file was rolled in the way shown in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. This is a working code.
It also avoids reading file info on every log append.
Instead, it will work on first file rollover. For time based or size based. Both.
Once it is in the process of compressing the current file. It will gzip exiting older files too. That was left after the application was stopped.
It will not require recoding all the RollingFileAppender class.

```
public class CustomRollingFileAppender : RollingFileAppender
{
   
    override protected void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
    {
        var currentFile = this.File;
        base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();

        if (!currentFile.Equals(this.File))
        {
            CompressFileGzip(currentFile);
            var dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.File);
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName);
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(this.File);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (!file.EndsWith(this.File) && file.EndsWith(fileExtension))
                {
                    CompressFileGzip(file.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void CompressFileGzip(string fileToGzip)
    {
        if (!FileExists(fileToGzip))
        {
            return;
        }
        FileInfo fileToBeGZipped = new FileInfo(fileToGzip);
        FileInfo gzipFileName = new FileInfo(string.Concat(fileToBeGZipped.FullName, ".gz"));

        using (FileStream fileToBeZippedAsStream = fileToBeGZipped.OpenRead())
        {
            using (FileStream gzipTargetAsStream = gzipFileName.Create())
            {
                using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(gzipTargetAsStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    fileToBeZippedAsStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);
                }
            }
        }
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileToGzip);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the implementation of Masood, but instead of using the File property (which doesn't seem to be changed), I read the LogLog mesasges for the "Move [from] -> [to]" event.

Added a filetime to the gz to avoid multiple "myLog.xml.1.gz" conflict.
Didn't want to get into better sanitation of the filename.

```
public class CompressedRollingFileAppender : RollingFileAppender {
        private readonly Regex _moveRegex;
        private string _moveToFile = null;

        public CompressedRollingFileAppender() : base() {
            LogLog.LogReceived += LogReceived;
            _moveRegex = new Regex(@"^Moving \[(.+)\] -> \[(.+)\]$");
        }

        private void LogReceived(object source, LogReceivedEventArgs e) {
            var match = _moveRegex.Match(e.LogLog.Message);

            if (match.Groups[1].Value == this.File) {
                _moveToFile = match.Groups[2].Value;
            }
        }

        protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend() {
            var currentFile = this.File;
            base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();

            if (_moveToFile != null) {
                CompressFileGzip(_moveToFile);
                _moveToFile = null;
            }
        }

        private void CompressFileGzip(string fileToGzip) {
            if (!FileExists(fileToGzip)) {
                return;
            }

            FileInfo fileToBeGZipped = new FileInfo(fileToGzip);
            // filetime 
            var filetime = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            FileInfo gzipFileName = new FileInfo(string.Concat(fileToBeGZipped.FullName, "." + filetime + ".gz"));

            using (FileStream fileToBeZippedAsStream = fileToBeGZipped.OpenRead())
            using (FileStream gzipTargetAsStream = gzipFileName.Create())
            using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(gzipTargetAsStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                fileToBeZippedAsStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);

            System.IO.File.Delete(fileToGzip);
        }
    }
```