# how to make all old log on folder to be compressed at the end of day ?

Tags: log4net

I wrote some application that using log4net for writing logs. 
I want that at end of the day ( usually i have 4-6 log files at the end of day ) - all the log files will be compressed to zip file and after the compress the log files will deleted.

1. Is there any way to do it using the configuration file of log4net ?
2. If there is no way to do it by the config file - is there any other easy way to do it ?

Comment: How would log4net know it's the end of the day? I think it would easier to have it zip yesterday's log files at the start of the day. But of course it depends on whether your application is a web application, desktop application or service. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I just found this, that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276296/how-to-implement-auto-archiving-for-log-file-using-log4net

Comment: 1. No 2. Depends on what type of app it is.