# log4net RollingFileAppender compress old files

Tags: zip, compression, log4net, rollingfileappender

Is there an opportunity in log4net/RollingFileAppender to compress the old BackupFiles per configuration? I have found this property in the log4php, but not in log4net:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
    <appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderRollingFile">
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutSimple" />
        <param name="file" value="file.log" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="1MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender_ref ref="default" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

About 2 years ago the Answer for the same Question was  - "not possible". I wonder, if it is possible now. 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement auto archiving for log file using Log4Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276296/how-to-implement-auto-archiving-for-log-file-using-log4net)

Comment: @stuartd: you are right - it is the same question, but this was about 2 years ago and i hope, that now the archiving in the configuraiton is solved...

Comment: There is no option to do this now. The answer is the same as on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276296/how-to-implement-auto-archiving-for-log-file-using-log4net